# Changing the ID of a form element in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am finding that the following:

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { @id = "locationName" })`

will not change the id of that element from name to `locationName`, in MVC3 this would change the id of the element. why not in MVC4?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `@Html.EditorFor` is for view data not for html attributes.

You should be using `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead.